# I can't run the program in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

[image]

I created a project unchecked (Create project form template)
and added new class named demo.
but when after compiling, I couldn't run the code intellij didin't show me result.
"Edit configuration" only appeared like this:

[image]

I don't know what to do :(
I saw someone run the code using Intellij without writing package.
So I don't think that it doesn't work because I didn't write package.
What can I do?

Comment: Just make the project from a template. That will get you a main method

Comment: Next time, post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: @JBNizet The code isn't the exact problem, the Intellij options are

Comment: No. The problem is that the main method is not a main method. That is code, and IntelliJ didn't generate it. The OP wrote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the String[] args parameter in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Comment: Why should I write this code? Could you tell me the reason ?

Comment: The "main method" in a Java program must have the signature above to be used as the entry point of your program. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Add the `args` parameter to the `main` method. Then right click into the editor -> and select "Run demo.main()"